# A regular expression for FEN castling state?

Tags: regex

The FEN(Forsyth–Edwards Notation) format requires the castling state of a chess game to be recorded as a sequence of the characters `KQkq` in order. Any character(s) can be omitted, but if none are present, `-` is in its place.

It seems like this should be pretty easy to create a regular expression for. But I have searched the web, a lot, and I have not seen a correct regex for this.

I have seen `-|K?Q?k?q` but this is not correct as it doesn't match `K`, `Q`, or `k`, which are valid.
I have seen `-|[K|Q|k|q]{1,4}` and `-|[KQkq]{1,4}` but these are not correct as they allow duplicate characters and misordering.

It is possible to simply list all sequences, 16 with the dash. But that is not fun.

Can you build a regex that fits the rule? Thanks!

**Edit:** *Addressing Mr Jacobs' comments.* Thanks. I can elaborate that I tested the examples given and identified the inadequacies with Swift/Xcode 14. I am looking for a solution with bog standard regular expressions. I could solve the requested problem algorithmically with more Swift code but I am looking for a regular expression that I can inject into an otherwise operational larger regular expression I have already built, for an independent pre-test for compliance before I send it to an already-working initializer that chops up the FEN pieces and builds the game position. This will help ensure that bad input does not crash my code.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a search engine. Please show your coding effort and your passing and failing examples.

Comment: It's also helps to mention what language your regular expression is written in, as some engines are more powerful than others, and may have additional string methods beyond just regular expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first regex idea is the closest to what you need. Also the `q` should be optional. In addition there should be:

- `^` and `$` anchors to indicate that there should be no other surrounding characters
- A check that the input is not empty. You could for instance require that unless the input is `-`, the start of the input should represent a word break. This could be done with `\b`

So:

```
^(-|\bK?Q?k?q?)$
```

See [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/KtOkNH/1)

The `\b` ensures that there is a word break. In this regex it is tested when at the first position of the input string, and so it practically means it requires that the first character is alphanumeric. This is good enough to make sure the input is not empty. `\b` does not match an empty string.

Comment: Perfect. And extends nicely to Chess960: ^(-|\b[A-H]?[C-H]?[a-h]?[c-h]?|\bK?Q?k?q?)$. Thanks! (I don't really get the \b but it definitely works.)

Comment: Actually. I have found that it still matches "", at least in my swift code, which is a problem, but never mind. I've found a work-around I can live with.

Comment: It shouldn't match an empty string (I added explanation to my answer). It *requires* that the first input character is alphanumeric. I suppose there is something else going on in your swift code.

Comment: Yeah it is odd. In regex101, it doesn't seem to match but in swift it does. I will investigate.

Comment: I don't know how much you or any reader wants to get into the weeds, but swift's .components(separatedBy: " ") returns a "" between two spaces and .firstMatch(of: /^(-|\bK?Q?k?q?)$/) returns a match of "", not nil (no match). As I say though, I have a work around. Thanks for your help.

Comment: To test this yourself try: print("See nothing between x and y: x\("".firstMatch(of: /^(-|\bK?Q?k?q?)$/)!.1)y")

Comment: I don't know swift, so I cannot help with that. If you want you could post a new swift-oriented question (not related to chess notation). You could try to reduce the regex and string to the smallest regex to reproduce the behaviour.